# C# Trigger EventHandler with parameters

Tags: c#, eventhandler

Hello i want to add a feature to my app but i just can't figure out.
i want to pass some arguments or at least 1 argument to EventHandler using subscriber.

That argument will allow me to do some check and then trigger event based on that argument.

```
public class Client
{
    public Client()
    {
        GameAPI api = new GameAPI();
        api.AddedPlayerEvent += Api_ClarkAdded;
        api.Do();
    }

    private void Api_ClarkAdded(object sender, GameAPI.AddedPlayerEvents e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("User Clark found");
    }
}


public class GameAPI
{
    public event EventHandler<AddedPlayerEvents> AddedPlayerEvent;
    List<AddedPlayerEvents> AddedPlayers = new List<AddedPlayerEvents>();
    public GameAPI()
    {
        // some code to simulate generating some data
        AddedPlayers.Add(new AddedPlayerEvents("Player1","James"));
        AddedPlayers.Add(new AddedPlayerEvents("Player2", "Clark"));
        AddedPlayers.Add(new AddedPlayerEvents("Player3", "Steve"));
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        // simulating code ...
        //trigger event
        if (AddedPlayers.Any(f => f.Name == "Clark")) /*value Clark should come from client using subsciber or something else*/
        {
            OnPlayerAdded(AddedPlayers.First(f => f.Name == "Clark"));
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPlayerAdded(AddedPlayerEvents e)
    {
        EventHandler<AddedPlayerEvents> handler = AddedPlayerEvent;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    public class AddedPlayerEvents
    {
        public string Pseudo { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public AddedPlayerEvents(string pseudo, string name)
        {
            Pseudo = pseudo;
            Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a simplified version of what i want to do so i try to make it simple so you can deal with it without garbadge stuff.

I already made a search but all i can find is the parameters is visible only in the client in the Methode handler not transmitted to the EventHandler, i think t should be stored somewhere that he can fetch for them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question's unclear to me. I see at least 3 different ways to interpret your stated goal: 1) you want the event raised for each added player, and want the event handler to trigger only for a specific, hard-coded one; 2) you want the event for each player, but want to reuse a common event handler that can be passed the name of the player to trigger; or 3) you want to pass the name of the player to the `Do()` method and have it raise the event only for the desired player. The third's the closest to the code you have now, but is the least conventional in terms of how events are usually used.

Comment: Please edit your question so that it is clear about what it is you actually want the code to do. Make sure you describe how what the code does now is different from what you want, what you have tried in order to make it do what you want, and what _specifically_ you need help with. Please also read [ask] for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: Why can't you pass the value "Clark" to the method "Do" from class Client ? Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: Well i don"t wanted to pass the parameters on the Do methode, hoping that there is another way to deal directly with the EventHandler subscriber but it seems not exist

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Thanks for the clarification. I think you don't fully understand how the event subscription mechanism works. Let me explain this on example. I refactored your code a little bit:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Client client = new Client();
    }
}

public class Client
{
    public Client()
    {
        GameAPI api = new GameAPI();
        api.PlayerAdded += Api_PlayerAdded;
        api.AddPlayer(new Player("Player2", "Clark"));
    }

    private void Api_PlayerAdded(object sender, PlayerAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"API PlayerAdded event has triggered. Arguments: e.Player.Name = {e.Player.Name}, e.Player.Pseudo = {e.Player.Pseudo}");
    }
}

public class PlayerAddedEventArgs: EventArgs
{
    public PlayerAddedEventArgs(Player player)
    {
        Player = player;
    }

    public Player Player { get; }
}

public class Player
{
    public Player(string pseudo, string name)
    {
        Pseudo = pseudo;
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Pseudo { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
}

public class GameAPI
{
    private List<Player> players = new List<Player>();

    public event EventHandler<PlayerAddedEventArgs> PlayerAdded;

    public void AddPlayer(Player player)
    {
        players.Add(player);
        OnPlayerAdded(new PlayerAddedEventArgs(player));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPlayerAdded(PlayerAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayerAdded?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

The two main classes here are `GameAPI` and `Client`.

`GameAPI` class:

1. Keeps track of all added players in the private `players` list.
2. Provides an `AddPlayer` method allowing clients to add players.
3. Provides a `PlayerAdded` event to notify clients that a player has been added.

`Client` class:

1. Subscribes to the `PlayerAdded` event exposed by the `GameAPI`.
2. Calls `AddPlayer` method to add the new player.

`AddPlayer` method adds the player to the internal `players` list and calls `OnPlayerAdded` which notifies all subscribed clients about the new player. This notification causes the `Api_PlayerAdded` method in all subscribed instances of the `Client` class to be called. The added player will be accessible as the `Player` property in the `e` argument passed to this method.

---

**Original answer:**

I don't see any issues with your code. I modified the `Api_JamesAdded` method to make sure it works properly, so the full code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Client client = new Client();
    }
}

public class Client
{
    public Client()
    {
        GameAPI api = new GameAPI();
        api.AddedPlayerEvent += Api_JamesAdded;
        api.Do();
    }

    private void Api_JamesAdded(object sender, GameAPI.AddedPlayerEvents e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {e.Name}, Pseudo: {e.Pseudo}");
    }
}

public class GameAPI
{
    public event EventHandler<AddedPlayerEvents> AddedPlayerEvent;
    List<AddedPlayerEvents> AddedPlayers = new List<AddedPlayerEvents>();
    public GameAPI()
    {
        // some code to simulate generating some data
        AddedPlayers.Add(new AddedPlayerEvents("Player1", "James"));
        OnPlayerAdded(AddedPlayers.First(f => f.Pseudo == "Player1"));

        AddedPlayers.Add(new AddedPlayerEvents("Player2", "Clark"));
        OnPlayerAdded(AddedPlayers.First(f => f.Pseudo == "Player2"));

        AddedPlayers.Add(new AddedPlayerEvents("Player3", "Steve"));
        OnPlayerAdded(AddedPlayers.First(f => f.Pseudo == "Player3"));
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        // simulating code ...
        //trigger event
        if (AddedPlayers.Any(f => f.Name == "Clark")) /*value Clark should come from client using subsciber or something else*/
        {
            OnPlayerAdded(AddedPlayers.First(f => f.Name == "Clark"));
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPlayerAdded(AddedPlayerEvents e)
    {
        EventHandler<AddedPlayerEvents> handler = AddedPlayerEvent;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    public class AddedPlayerEvents
    {
        public string Pseudo { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public AddedPlayerEvents(string pseudo, string name)
        {
            Pseudo = pseudo;
            Name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

This code prints:

```
Name: Clark, Pseudo: Player2
```

If this is not what you expected, please post the expected output.

Comment: The code work fine because i hard code the value "Clark" that should come as a variable instead.